# Visual Studio Immediate Window - Problems with Web Applications

Tags: visual-studio, immediate-window

Does anyone have any experience in using the Visual Studio Immediate Window with Web Applications? I have VS2010 Ultimate, and the immediate window works just as expected (i can evaluate code while in design mode), when using for ex. Console Applications. But when i try for ex. calling a static method in the immediate window while in a Web Application project, i get the error **'The expression cannot be evaluated while in design mode.'** I did some googleing and the best answer i could find was in a comment on [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/09/28/the-immediate-window-working-with-members-vstiptool0095.aspx)
post, saying :

*Keep in mind that if you are working with Web Applications you need to debug your app and hit a breakpoint (just place a breakpoint on your start page of the project) before evaluating from the immediate window. Otherwise you will be greeted with " The expression cannot be evaluated while in design mode." or "The expression cannot be evaluated while in run mode. "*

Does this mean that the Immediate Window can only be used if I've started the application and hit a breakpoint? And if so, does anyone have any idea why this is true for web applications?

Thanks

Comment: I have only ever used the immediate window in debug mode.